# bitmap height and width auto scaled for drawable from res folders but not for drawable created from URL

Tags: android, image, bitmap, drawable

I am just trying to download images from URL and turn it into a Drawable and set it as DrawableLeft of a TextView, however for those images that I loaded by using

> `getResources().getDrawable(context, R.drawable.blahblahblah)`

the **mBitmapHeight** and **mBitmapWidth** properties of the **Drawable** object are automatically set to around 2 times of the original width and height of the image (
and I have the same image for 3 different scale in mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folder), while for images that I downloaded from a URL, I specified the density in the bitmap object for those images downloaded:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
bitmap.setDensity(metrics.densityDpi);
```

and created a BitmapDrawable

```
BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
```

but these 2 properties are set to a value that equals to the original height and width of the image, which results in the drawable to be extremely small when I set its bound using intrinsic height and width.

I don't know how the system sets the height and weight of differently for images loaded from res folder and downloaded from URL. I will be really appreciated if anyone can share some thoughts on this. Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

I set the drawable bounds like this:

```
    if (icon != null) {
        int lh = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int lw = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, lw, lh);
    }
```

"icon" is a Drawable. And then I set this icon to be

```
textView.setCompoundDrawables(icon, null, rightIcon, null);
```

Comment: Depends on the resolution of the image from either from an external source or from your own drawables. I believe you will still be able to scale the images according to you needs and its not dependent on the source you are getting the assets from.

Comment: @mike20132013 Thanks Mike, I know that but I want it to be dynamically scaled and in order to do so I would imagine that I have to scale based on device density but the height and width value the scaling gives me still makes the image too small on the screen after setting the drawable bounds using intrinsic size.

Comment: set this code after downloading the image from url, not before it.

Comment: @TusharPandey Of course the bounds is set after the download completed, otherwise how can I get the intrinsic value ?